# Is there a way to write a for loop in R to batch convert tif to asc files?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a loop in R to automatically select files and convert them to a different file type (.tif to .asc). I don't want to manually select each file, is there a way to do this in R?

This is what I've been doing manually, but it's slow and tedious.

```
bioclim19<-file.choose()

bioclim19asc<-raster(bioclim19)
bioclim19asc<-aggregate(bioclim19asc,fact=2)

writeRaster(bioclim19asc,"bioclim19.asc",format="ascii")
```

Comment: Instead of `file.choose` use `list.files` with a pattern “\\\.tif”then loop over the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by IRFTM, the code below might fit your requirements..
let me know if that helps..

```
# directory address where your files are
setwd("path/to/directory")

# list of all (and only) .tif files in that directory
tif_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.tif$")

# loop through each file and convert to .asc format
for (f in tif_files) {
  # read in the raster object
  rasterObject <- raster(f)
  
  # aggregate the raster object
  aggRaster <- aggregate(rasterObject, fact = 2)
  
  # write aggregated raster object into a .asc file
  writeRaster(aggRaster, file.path(filePath_toSave_File, 
               gsub("\\.tif$", ".asc", f)), format = "ascii")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! While attempting to run this code for my loop, I ran into one small error. Instead of having gsub("\\.tif$",".asc",file), I had to change the "file" to "f" (as in "f in tif_files"). Otherwise, I would continuously get an error. This way, R knew to convert each f in the list of tif files to asc as separate iterations.

Comment: Actually correct, typo from me... but, did it work as intended?

Comment: It did work as intended after fixing the typo. Thank you very much!